# message-display-box text over runs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have

```
<div class="panel-body message-display-box">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.Body)</div>
```

Problem is, the text within modelItem.Body is very long and over runs the width of the containing div. I don't mind either wrapping or truncating the text since I have a button that allows the user to download the full message.

What's the best way to use bootstrap to wrap the text if it reaches the width of the containing div?

I have tried updating to the following but made no difference:

```
<div class="panel-body message-display-box">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.Body, new { @class = "wrap-text:wrap" })</div>
```

Comment: it's something like: **wrap-text:wrap;**. But as a suggestion, scrap bootstrap.

Comment: http://makandracards.com/makandra/5883-use-css-text-overflow-to-truncate-long-texts

Comment: I tried changing as per update but it made no difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
<div class="panel-body">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.MessageData, new { @style = "word-wrap: break-word;" })</div>
```